# Getting an unknown function error using setValue or getRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am kind of new to this scripting but not new to programming – but run in to this problem with the:

```
      var appoved = "APPROVED";
      ws.getRange(row, V).setValue(appoved); // Note: argument 3, 4, is optional actual worksheet
```

Here is the code below the setup and lines above:

```
    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2020members");  
    var data = ws.getRange("B2:U" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();  
    data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[19] == true });  
    var V = 20; // Col 20 on sheet 
    data.forEach(function(row) { 
          ws.getRange(row, V).setValue(appoved); // This is the line with the problem 
      // unknown function error

    }) ;
```

What I am trying to do is put the letters APRROVED in a specific row at column V in the spread sheet the words APRROVED and move to the next row and if condition exits put the same thing in same place and move on to next row.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a redacted version of the sheet with us to debug? I'm unable to execute the code beyond line 2 as it says 'Range not found' for `var data = ws.getRange("B2:U" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();`

Comment: In this line `data.forEach(function(row) { 
          ws.getRange(row, V).setValue(appoved);` row is an array not a single value

Comment: row is a array and should be the row in the spreadsheet that the script is currently on but the value is .setValue (appoved) the value is appoved which is the text stored in the var appoved I want to stuff it in the 20 column on the active row.

Comment: What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

`data.forEach(function(row,i) { 
          ws.getRange(i+2, V).setValue(appoved); // This is the line with the problem`
The second parameter of the forEach Method is the index and you can take the index And the starting row Get the current row number which is required for the signature of the get range method.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for helping yes it works i will try to write something up tonight FHS